# How to write CSS media query , that should applicable only for IE9 and IE 10?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10

Currently the CSS class that I am using is:

```
body.srp-map-view {
  .page-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 49px; 
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
}
```

If it is IE 9 or IE 10 I have to add margin-top: 29px; property to above class.

I tried some media queries which I found in stackoverflow but they are not working. Is there any other way to write other than media queries ?

Comment: you could put it into a separate css file, then use IE's conditional comments, `<!--[if IE9] --><link href="ie9stuff.css" /><![endif]-->`

Answer (score 0):

Try using IE conditional statement...

```
<!--[if gte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This may be useful..

https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Conditional comments aren't supported in IE10+

Answer (score 0):

The method described here should work for IE10 and up, which don't support conditional comments any more:

https://css-tricks.com/ie-10-specific-styles/

As the article says, you're better off using Feature Detection rather than Browser Detection, if at all possible.